# PrimeFaces TabView no results displayed on submit

Tags: jsf, primefaces, submit, tabview

The following code contains two tabs and basic code from showcase example. I tried to put this code into a xhtml and did ui:include within the tabs and also just adding them within tabs as list below. Either way when I click the submit button, do not see any results displayed.

Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

 <h:form> 
 <p:tabView id="tabs" orientation="left" styleClass=".borderlessUnit" dynamic="true">
    <p:tab id="tab0" title="Test Menu 1">
       <p:layout id="layout0" style="min-height:600px;">
          <p:layoutUnit position="center" resizable="true" styleClass="borderlessUnit">
                <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name 1:" style="font-weight:bold"/>  
                <p:inputText id="name" value="#{personBean.firstname}" />  
                <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display"/>  
                <h:outputText value="#{personBean.firstname}" id="display" />  
          </p:layoutUnit>                            
       </p:layout>   
     </p:tab>
     <p:tab id="tab1" title="Test Menu 2">
       <p:layout id="layout1" style="min-height:600px;">
         <p:layoutUnit position="center" resizable="true" styleClass="borderlessUnit">
                <h:outputLabel for="name1" value="Name 2:" style="font-weight:bold"/>  
                <p:inputText id="name1" value="#{personBean.secondname}" />  
                <p:commandButton value="Submit1" update="display1"/>  
                <h:outputText value="#{personBean.secondname}" id="display1" />  
         </p:layoutUnit>
       </p:layout>
      </p:tab>    
</p:tabView>
</h:form>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us your backing bean code.

Comment: You are aware that the command buttons are doing nothing (no `action`) but simply refreshing the view, which won't change because the value of `display` will remain the same as before the button was clicked

Answer (score 0):

In use manual of PrimeFaces is documented that you should avoid nesting layout and layout units inside forms, and that each layout unit should have its own form, instead. So remove form, and put separated form inside each `layoutUnit`

Comment: thanks for your reply, Tested with two options, Added Form inside LayoutUnit and Also removed LayoutUnit and Layout and instead just gave a panelgrid inside each form. Still no results displayed.